# Binding issues with ICommand on Xamarin Forms PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am currently working on xamarin forms in VS2017 pcl project. I am trying to do binding to toggle the visibility of a view via tap gestures on an image. However, it seems like theres an issue with toggling the visibility of 2 views using binding. At any point of time i would only like to show one of the views.
Would anyone be kind enough to help me with this?

Below is what I have in my project, all codes involved

MainViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App3
{
    public class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isView1Visible;
        private bool _isView2Visible;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var ev = PropertyChanged;
            ev?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public bool isView1Visible
        {
            get { return _isView1Visible; }

            set
            {
                if (_isView1Visible != value)
                {
                    _isView1Visible = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public bool isView2Visible
        {
            get { return _isView2Visible; }

            set
            {
                if (_isView2Visible != value)
                {
                    _isView2Visible = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        } 


        public static void AddTapAction(View view, Action action)
        {
            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) =>
            {
                action();
            };
            view.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
        }

        public ICommand ShowView1Command
    {
        get
        {
            return _showView1Command ??
                   (_showView1Command =
                       new Command(() =>  showView1()));
        }
    }

        public ICommand ShowView2Command
        {
            get
            {
                return _showView2Command ??
                       (_showView2Command =
                           new Command(() => showView2()));
            }
        }

        bool showView1()
        {
            isView1Visible = true;
            isView2Visible = false;
            return true;
        }

        bool showView2()
        {
            isView1Visible = false;
            isView2Visible = true;
            return true;
        }

        ICommand _showView1Command;
    ICommand _showView2Command;

 }
}
```

Subview1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App3
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SubView1 : ContentView
    {
        public SubView1()
        {
            ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            BindingContext = ViewModel;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Subview1.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App3.SubView1">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Text="View 1" IsVisible="{Binding isView1Visible}"></Label>
          <Label Text="View 2" IsVisible="{Binding isView2Visible}"></Label>

        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
```

Subview2.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App3.SubView2">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
          <Image x:Name="Btn1" Source="icon.png">
              <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowView1Command}" CommandParameter="Btn1" />
              </Image.GestureRecognizers>

            </Image>
          <Image x:Name="Btn2" Source="icon.png">
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowView2Command}" CommandParameter="Btn2" />
          </Image.GestureRecognizers></Image>  
        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
    </ContentView>
```

Subview2.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App3
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SubView2 : ContentView
    {
        public SubView2()
        {
            ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            BindingContext = ViewModel;
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App3"
             x:Class="App3.MainPage">

     <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
         <local:SubView1></local:SubView1>
         <local:SubView2></local:SubView2>
         <Label Text="This is loaded"></Label>
     </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App3
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            BindingContext = ViewModel;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to toggle you should use only one private bool variable in the model. public isView1Visible and IsView2Visible can be implemented based on that one variable. In addition you even can have one public variable and bind it to 2 views, one - directly and second via inverse converter. I recently saw one answer showing how to do that in SO. Do some search and you will find it

Comment: Yes I do agree with what you said. It could be based on one variable. However the issue here is I binded them to 2 different variable which I did do an update of the variables values using Icommand. But I do not know why it does not work. Do you perhaps have any idea

Comment: if you share sample project I can take a look

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxwJ_UygiRkKZXJvcmdiZ2FIOWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: shared it in the above link. please help

Comment: You are creating MainViewModel 3 times - one in main view and 2 more in subviews. This is not going to work. Use only one MainViewModel.

Comment: okay thank you. That solved my problem  :D